# PHP - Get specific value from curl_exec

Tags: php, curl

I am doing some API work using cURL. I am logging out the session response like this:

```
$headers = array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '. $accessToken,
        'Content-Type: image/png',
        'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $filename .'"',
        'Content-Length: '. $fileSize
    );

$curlSession = curl_init($apiURL);
curl_setopt($attachmentSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);   
curl_setopt($attachmentSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);   
curl_setopt($attachmentSession, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fileStream);
curl_setopt($attachmentSession, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fileSize);
curl_setopt($attachmentSession, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
//curl_setopt($attachmentSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
curl_setopt($attachmentSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($attachmentSession, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
$curlResponse = curl_exec($curlSession);
print_r($curlResponse);
```

This gives me the following output:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 29 Jun 2017 18:31:37 GMT Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 316 Connection: close {"message":"SUCCESS","resultCode":0,"result":{"id":348293483294,"name":"smartsheet.png","attachmentType":"FILE","mimeType":"image/png","sizeInKb":85,"parentType":"ROW","parentId":32423423423,"createdBy":{"name":"Test","email":"test@test.com"},"createdAt":"2017-06-29T18:31:37Z"},"version":404}
```

How can I access the value associated with parentId from this response? I tried the following:

```
$curlResponse->parentId
```

and

```
$curlResponse[parentId]
```

but those didn't work.

Comment: Where's the rest of your curl setup? You must be setting the option to get headers also. Try without that option and `json_decode` the result

Comment: @dan08 updated with the rest of my curl setup

Comment: @dan08 thank you, that was it! Once I removed the `CURLOPT_HEADER` line I was able to use `json_decode`. Please add as answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response body returned from curl contains the "raw http response", including headers and body.
You can discard the headers by

```
curl_setopt($attachmentSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

This way you will only get the respone body and you can `json_decode` it.
Note however that discarding headers may hurt you later, e.g. if you will need to check certain responses.
You can obtain the headers using `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` which allows you to set a callback function to parse the response headers